# Split CSV column into two

Tags: powershell, csv

Trying to split the column `SchedTime` at the hyphen into two columns.

Example data:

```
SchedTime,Data2,Data3
00:00-00:30,blah,alsoblah
08:00-08:30,yadda,yaddayadda
```

Desired result:

```
SchedTime,Data2,Data3,Start,End
00:00-00:30,blah,alsoblah,00:00,00:30
08:00-08:30,yadda,yaddayadda,08:00,08:30
```

Attempt:

```
Import-Csv $SAMTemp | foreach {
    $Start, $End = $_.SchedTime.Split("-")

    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Start -Value $Start
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name End -Value $End
} | Export-Csv $SAMTemp2 -NoTypeInformation
```

My result is a blank CSV file.

I would like to append the data to the original CSV, but so far if I try to write it to its own file, I get a blank result.

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907409/powershell-split-csv-column-value-into-two-seperate-column-values), but am not having any luck.

Comment: `foreach` should produce some output: add a new line with `$_` before `}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't output the modified object back to the pipeline, hence your input is silently discarded. Add a `$_` at the end of the loop to fix this (as [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636519/split-csv-column-into-two/42636650#comment72400699_42636519) suggested in the comments to your question):

```
Import-Csv ... | foreach {
    ...
    $_
} | Export-Csv ...
```

With that said, you could also use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to the get your desired result:

```
Import-Csv ... |
    Select-Object *,
        @{n='Start';e={$_.SchedTime.Split('-')[0]}},
        @{n='End';e={$_.SchedTime.Split('-')[1]}} |
    Export-Csv ...
```

**Addendum:** If you want to append to the original you cannot use `Export-Csv` for that. Even if you do it correctly by completely reading the file before processing the content:

```
(Import-Csv your.csv) | ... | Export-Csv your.csv -NoType -Append
```

the result won't be what you expect. That is because PowerShell determines the output fields from the first object in the list (which in case of appending to a CSV is the first record from the CSV). Meaning that the additional fields won't be written to the file.

You can sort of work around the issue like this:

```
(Import-Csv your.csv) | ... |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Add-Content your.csv
```

but that will still leave you with the new column titles missing from the CSV, even if the actual values are being written.

My recommendation is to separate modifed from original content (i.e. write the modified records to a new file). If you must append to the original file, add the new columns to the original records before appending the modified records, e.g. like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv your.csv -Header 'SchedTime','Data2','Data3','Start','End'

$csv | Export-Csv your.csv -NoType

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Start, $End = $_.SchedTime.Split("-")
    $_.Start = $Start
    $_.End   = $End
    $_
} | Export-Csv your.csv -NoType -Append
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not going to bother appending, but I appreciate it.